# What is a non-geometric proof to prove the sine addition formula?

Tags: trigonometry

What is a non-geometric proof to prove the sine addition formula?

I know that method that using euler's constant or taylor's series works, but is there any others?

Search the google with the "non-geometric proof of sine addition formula" only provide me with the geometric way...

Anybody want to answer?

Comment: How do you define the $\sin$ function ?

Comment: @Belgi - The most basic one in High School.

Comment: If you are given a geomtric definition then the proof is also geometric.

Comment: @Belgi - Any of the definition on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sine.html

Comment: Did you study calculus before ? some of the definitions are with power series

Comment: @Belgi - Except the euler's constant and taylor's series method...

Comment: @Victor perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189016/deriving-the-addition-formula-of-sin-u-from-a-total-differential-equation/189101#189101 will be of interest. In that thread we discuss definitions of sine... this sort of question always comes back to that.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook - Any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-geometric proof of DeMoivre's theorem that does not use Euler's theorem.  But the result of section 3 (before DeMoivre's theorem is proved) is the angle addition formulas, if you equate components: http://www.dfcd.net/articles/demoivre.pdf